printing in oracle apex using plsql dynamic content error
I want to print a tax report using Oracle Apex using plsql dynamic content.
The result must be for all clients during a certain period, and this period is determined by two items, from_date and to_date
An error appears when the exact drag returns (SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows)
I tried to do it with another condition, which is the cust_id, but I got the same error
Any Help?
this is a part of my query
    htp.p('<tr>');
    htp.p('<th>م</th>');
    htp.p('<th> كود الفاتورة</th>');
    htp.p('<th> تاريخ الفاتورة</th>');
    htp.p('<th> اجمالي الفاتورة</th>');
    htp.p('<th> اجمالي الضريبة</th>');
    htp.p('<th> اسم العميل</th>');
    htp.p('<th> كود العميل</th>');
    htp.p('<th> الرقم الضريبي للعميل</th>'); 
    htp.p('</tr>');
   FOR item_row IN invoice_details LOOP
    BEGIN
    select z.inv_code,z.inv_date,z.inv_total,z.vta_total,cust_name,cust_id,cust_vat
    INTO  V_INV_CODE ,v_inv_date,v_inv_total,v_vta_total,V_CUST_NAME,V_CUST_ID,V_CUST_VAT   
    from INV_MASTER z,CRM_CUSTOMER   CRM 
    where inv_date between :P87_FROM_DATE and :P87_TO_DATE
    --and z.customer_name = CRM.cust_id
   order by inv_code;  
htp.p('<tr>');
htp.p('<td>' || counter || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || item_row.inv_code|| '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || item_row.inv_date || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || item_row.inv_total || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || item_row.vta_total || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || item_row.cust_name || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || item_row.cust_id || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || item_row.cust_vat || '</td>');
htp.p('</tr>');
        counter := counter + 1; 

and this is the error i had got

I have edited my query such as in the question you have mentioned but get the same error

You want to use nested loops FOR item_row IN invoice_details LOOP FOR sub_item_row IN (<your-select-query-without-the-into-clause>) LOOP <do stuff with item_row and sub_item_row> END LOOP; END LOOP;
